# gSOAP C++ - UTF8 Data encoding

Tags: character-encoding, gsoap

I have a problem with gSOAP C++. 
I want to read some records from a postgres database. For that I set the client_encoding to UTF-8.

In the sent.log of gSOAP I have those characters:

Ã¼berstr.  or  Ã¶de (First should be a "ü" and the second one a "ö").

If I set the client_encoding during the database selection to "LATIN1", the request is correct.

What should I do to send the UTF-8 Data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `SOAP_C_UTFSTRING` flag to initialize the context and to construct a proxy object. With this flag you can store UTF-8 in regular octet-based strings (i.e. `char*` and `std::string`).

Or perhaps use wide string members in your classes (e.g. run wsdl2h with a typemap.dat that maps XSD strings to wide strings).